# How to decide if two estimators are unbiased and consistent

Tags: regression, self-study, unbiased-estimator, consistency

How can I decide for the following estimators ($\bar\beta_1 $  and $\tilde\beta_1 $)  if they are unbiased and/or consistent for $\beta_1 $ ?

Lets assume I have a normal linear reg. model
$\ y_i $ = $\beta_1 $ + $\beta_2 x_i $ + $\epsilon_i$

error term is i.i.d

$\tilde\beta_1 $ = ($\ x_2y_1 - x_1y_2$)/ ($\ x_2 -x_1$)

$\bar\beta_1 $ = (n + $\ln(n)$) / n * $\hat\beta_1 $

---

For $\tilde\beta_1$ I would argue that it is unbiased and consistent since we know that usually $\ b = y_1 − mx_1 = (x_2y_1 − x_1y_2)/(x_2 − x_1)$ is the intercept on the y-axisas we know from analytical geometry.

Comment: Have you tried applying the definitions?  Incidentally, $\tilde\beta_1$ doesn't seem to be an estimator: it's merely a modification of a parameter.  If the parameter is known, then estimation is superfluous; and if it's unknown, you can't compute it!

Comment: Both are estimators in this case; we know $\hat\beta $ is unbiased

Comment: Now that you put the hat on the $\beta_1$, you finally do have a legitimate estimator for $\tilde \beta$! Why doesn't that immediately answer your question?

Comment: How is that the case? How can I show that?

Comment: As I first wrote, *apply the definitions.*  It comes down to observing that $(n+\log(n))/n$ is never equal to $1$ when $n\gt 1$ but converges to $1$ as $n$ grows large.  Incidentally, in case this question survives for any time, I wish to point out that in an earlier edit you switched the bar and tilde--an action whose complete lack of any benefit towards clarifying the question only leaves the impression you're trying to make the comments confuse other readers.

Comment: So $ \bar\beta $ is only consistent as n goes to infinity. That is understood but how to you check for $ \tilde\beta $ . Apologize for the confusion created.

Comment: How do I show that $\tilde\beta_1$ is not 1